# ClearDB on Heroku throws an error when running a migration to create a new table that has a `details` field of type `json`

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-5, mysql2, cleardb

I am running a `Rails 5.2.2` and `ruby 2.6.3` app on Heroku backed by ClearDB database.

**NOTE: Locally this all works fine**

my gem file has the mysql2 version as such:
`gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4', '< 0.6.0'`

When I attempt to run a migration to create a new table that has a `details` field of type `json` it fails with a syntax error.

`Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'json'`

Removing the `details` field of type `json` and re-running the migration succeeeds.

Here is an example of the contents of the migration.

```
class InitTables < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :services do |t|
      t.string :public_id, null: false, index: { unique: true }
      t.json :details
    end
  end
end
```

This is the error message: 
`Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'json'`

Answer (score 4):

I faced same issues with ClearDB (Ignite plan). Switched to JAWS_DB (free plan) and migration was run successfully.

Comment: thank you so much for this, i was actually using laravel, these frustrated me for days

Answer (score 3):

According to the ClearDB support, `5.7` version of MySQL is required to be compatible with my migration to use a field of `json` type.

The Heroku Ignite, Punch, Drift and Scream plans shared resource plans are currently only available on clusters running 5.5 or 5.6 (5.6 in Europe) versions of MySQL and **I AM ON the Heroku Ignite plan**.

To solve this issue I'll need a dedicated resource(instance) plans that can be configured to use 5.5, 5.6, or 5.7 version of MySQL.